# Derived equivalences implying isomorphism of Hochschild cohomologies, question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $k$ be a field, let $A$ and $B$ be associative unital $k$-algebras, in this paper (http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/publ/dih.pdf) Keller says that if there's an equivalence of derived categories

$\mathcal{D}(A) \xrightarrow{\sim}\mathcal{D}(B)$,

there's an isomorphism of graded algebras between their Hochschild cohomologies $HH(A,A)$ and $HH(B,B)$.

I wanted to ask:

**Is $\mathcal{D}(A)$ the derived category of left $A$-modules, or the derived category of $A$-bimodules ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He means the derived category of left (or right ... I forget whether he's left- or right-handed) modules. But if there's an equivalence of derived categories of left modules, then there's also an equivalence of derived categories of bimodules, which is the key to the result you quote.

Comment: Thank you, sort of a dumb question, but does it work in the opposite direction? That is if the derived category of $A$-bimodules is equivalent to the derived category of $B$-bimodules, are the derived categories of left $A$-modules and left $B$-modules equivalent? Does that make sense?

Comment: @SamuelM It makes sense. There are trivial ways to get counterexamples over non-algebraically closed fields; for example, take $k=A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\mathbb{H}$, in which case the bimodule categories are equivalent, but the module categories aren't. But I don't know any more interesting examples.

Comment: Glad I asked that, very very interesting all this, thanks again.